# Dynamically update three graphics simultaneously

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I have a problem. How can I get three arrows in to update simultaneously? All work, but one by one.

```
wsp = Table[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 2 \[Pi]/6, -9 \[Pi]/6, -\[Pi]/6}];
wsp1 = Table[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 15 \[Pi]/30, -60 \[Pi]/30, -\[Pi]/30}];
For[n = 1, n <= 12, n++, Pause[1]; g = n]
For[n = 1, n <= 60, n++, Pause[0.2]; h = n]
For[n = 1, n <= 12, n++, Pause[0.1]; j = n]
Graphics[{Table[{ColorData["TemperatureMap", i/12], 
     Disk[wsp[[i]], 0.2], Text[Style[i, Black, Bold], wsp[[i]]]}, {i, 
     1, 12}], , Thick, Black, Arrowheads[Large], 
   Dynamic[Arrow[{{0, 0}, .7 wsp[[g]]}]], 
   Dynamic[Arrow[{{0, 0}, .95 wsp1[[h]]}]], GrayLevel[.3], 
   Dynamic[Line[{{0, 0}, 0.8 wsp[[j]]}]], 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.3, 1.3}}}] // Framed
```

PS. Dont look at coordinates, i ll correct it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sec = 60;
min = 1/60;
hr = 1/60/12;
wsp = Table[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 2 \[Pi]/6, -9 \[Pi]/6, -\[Pi]/6}];
Animate[Graphics[{Table[{ColorData["TemperatureMap", i/12], 
 Disk[wsp[[i]], 0.2], Text[Style[i, Black, Bold], wsp[[i]]]}, 
 {i,1, 12}],Thick, Black, Arrowheads[Large], 
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Sin[min 2 Pi t], Cos[min 2 Pi t]}}], 
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, 0.8 {Sin[hr 2 Pi t], Cos[hr 2 Pi t]}}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.3, 1.3}}}]
, {t, 0, 60}]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe do you know how to add beep[] every hour?
i just thought about it:
`Table[Beep[]; {Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 2 \[Pi]/6, -9 \[Pi]/6, -\[Pi]/6}]` but it does not work

Comment: Hi @Karol. Try If[Mod[t,60]==0, Beep[]]. I am travelling, so can't evaluate it right now. You may have to use `Evaluate`.